# MS Access style custom dropdown list for combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I am making  C# application for database management, just wondering if there's any way to improve the style of a combo box dropdown list? Like, for example, display multiple columns of data, each in a visually separated cell?

Just for reference, my client wants to see it look like the MS Access drop down list below

[image]

EDIT:OH mod, the suggested link helps little, I am asking for the style of the user interface, not the actual data.
But nevermind, after explained to my client that this might slow down the development, he agreed to drop this feature, for now.

Comment: winform? wpf?... have you google for this?

Comment: Is this a WinForms or a WPF application?

Comment: Its a Windows Form. Yea I spent a few hours on Google for "custom combobox item", but no luck.

Comment: NOT a duplicate.  The difference is quite fundamental.  This question is asking for tab delimited column support.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149(v=vs.85).aspx  note specifically: LBS_MULTICOLUMN and LBS_COMBOBOX